# Is there a Pythonic generic "null dependency"?

Tags: python, dependencies

I often find myself in a situation where a class has an optional dependency.  For example, the `notifier` in the following.

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, notifier=None):
        self._notifier = notifier or DummyNotifier()

    def doTheBusiness(self):
        doSomeWork()
        self._notifier.notifyComplete()
```

As the `notifier` is optional, I have two choices:

- If no `notifier` is supplied, put a `DummyNotifier` in its place (as per the example above), where `DummyNotifier` is an implementation of the dependency that performs no actions
- In `doTheBusiness`, check whether `notifier` is None before calling anything on it

I prefer the first option for code readability, but it involves having to write a implementation for each dependency (albeit a very small one).

To avoid this, I've been thinking of a generic dependency as follows:

```
class GenericDependency(object):
    def generic(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
    def __getattr__(self, _):
        return self.generic
```

I can then call any method on this:

```
gd = GenericDependency()
gd.notifyComplete()
gd.anythingElse("also", "works", "with", any="arguments")
```

(This obviously only works for actions - not functions that require a return value.)

My question - (1) is this Pythonic (2) is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say 1) is a valid solution, also known as [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).
I see another possible solutions:
1) Remove the dependency and call `notifier` outside the `Example` class, i.e. after calling `doTheBusiness`
2) Maybe use [Obeserver Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)?